# TTViewController and popupViewController method

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, three20

I'm using a TTLauncherView and for that I declare a view controller as TTViewController, as is in TTCatalog tutorial app. Declare a TTLauncherView var inside that view, add items, and so on.

In my app's main view is a button calling the previous view with the following code:

```
-(void) switchToButtonOrderingView
{
    ButtonOrderingViewController *ButtonOrderingView=
    [[ButtonOrderingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ButtonOrderingViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    self.ButtonOrderingViewController = ButtonOrderingView; 
    [self.view insertSubview:ButtonOrderingView.view atIndex:10];
}
```

When I press the button the app brakes up at this method which belongs to TTViewController.m:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  UIViewController* popup = [self popupViewController]; //brakes up here
  if (popup) {
    return [popup shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
  } else {
    return [super shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation];
  }
}
```

and the error goes like that:

> [ButtonOrderingViewController popupViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Checked to see Three20 Class Hierarchy and TTViewController is a UIViewController subclass.

popupViewController is a TTPopViewController (and its subclasses) method! Which I'm not using nor do TTCatalog tutorial app. I'm lost. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Would love to get a response for this. Am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Had the same issue and found the error!

This is what happens when you forget to add -ObjC and/or -all_load to Other Linker Flags according to the Three20 setup instructions. Could be that you added them to the project level, and have an overriding setup at a lower level - that was the case for me.

Comment: Note that this is a pretty common problem any time you're using a 3rd-party static library that was written in Objective-C. You can get more info on what these flags do by going to http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2006/qa1490.html.

To quote: "The -ObjC flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. [...] The -all_load flag forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code."