# Three20's UIKit extensions don't seem to be being "included" properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, three20

So, we have a project using the Three20 Library from Facebook (http://github.com/facebook/three20), and we're trying to compile against the latest version (HEAD from Github).

Previously it's worked fine, but something has now changed :)

The error I'm getting is an unrecognized selector on TTTableViewController:

```
[TTViewControllerSubClass popupViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

(There's another question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139534/ttviewcontroller-and-popupviewcontroller-method))

I checked TTViewController, and it turns out we don't actually need to call popupSubView, so I commented that out. I then get this error:

```
-[UIImageView removeAllSubviews]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

So, I checked the locations of both these methods in Three20, and they are in UIViewControllerAdditions.m and UIViewAdditions.m, respectively. So this makes me think that Three20 is adding some methods to the basic UIKit classes, and these methods aren't actually getting included the way they should be.

Problem is, I get stuck there :) I've got no clue how to make UIKit include these classes, or "fix" Three20 (if it is indeed a Three20 problem) to make it work.

So I'm hoping some kind soul here will slog through my incredibly long problem description and point me in the right direction!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like upgrading Three20 and following the instructions at http://three20.info/setup/existing I managed to get this working!